# Pressenting an Xml document

Tags: css, xml, xslt, document

So I had some stuff to write out.
The information was pretty regular, and fixed format. 
(Stats for a creature in an RPG).
So I thought, Xml is a great format for this (better than say Latex).

Here is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Entity type="Oni">
  <Fluff>
    <Name>Wakaalu no Oni</Name>
    <Description>
      It is a bit too angular to be human, its limbs look almost sharp.
    </Description>
  </Fluff>
  <Cruch>

    <Rings>
      <Earth Stamina="4" Willpower="4" />
      <Fire Agility="5" Intelligence="4" />
      <Water Perception="3" Strength="3" />
      <Air Awareness="3" Reflexes="4" />
    </Rings>
    <Skills>
      <Skill Name="Jujitsu" Rank="3" />
    </Skills>

    <Defense>
      <ToHit TN="30" />
      <Reduction amount="10, 4 against Jade" />
    </Defense>

    <Wounds>
      <WoundRank penalty="+5" taken="16" />
      <WoundRank penalty="+10" taken="32" />
      <WoundRank penalty="+15" taken="48" />
      <WoundRank penalty="Dead" taken="72" />
    </Wounds>

    <Attacks>
      <Attack Name="Chop/Kick" attack="8k5" Damage="6k3" />      
    </Attacks>

    <Abilities>
      <SpecialAbilities>
        <SpecialAbility name="Honour Of Jidoku">
          <Effect>
            Any time anyone directly causes harm to come to the Oni, 
            they must make a willpower roll + honour,at TN=30.
            If they fail then one of the following affects takes place: (the duration is at the GM's discression). 
            <RolledResultTable>
              <Heading Result="Effect" Roll="1d100" />
              <Line Result="Immediately Lose 1 Point of Honour" Roll="0" />
              <Line Result="Compassion: You must spend a Void point before you are able to act on behalf of someone of lower Status or social caste." Roll="1-10" />
              <Line Result="Courage: When facing an opponent of higher Glory or Status, or when facing a Shadowlands opponent, the TN of all rolls you make is increased by +5." Roll="11-20" />
              <Line Result="Courtesy: Any time you make a Social Skill Roll to apologize or avoid giving offense, you must call a Raise for no effect, or the roll will automatically fail." Roll="21-30" />
              <Line Result="Duty: You cannot spend Void Points to negate Wounds." Roll="31-40" />
              <Line Result="Honesty: You cannot spend Void points on any Sincerity Skill Roll to which the Honesty emphasis could apply (whether or not you have the emphasis)." Roll="41-50" />
              <Line Result="Honor: You cannot add your Honor Rank to any roll to resist Intimidation or Temptation." Roll="51-60" />
              <Line Result="Sincerity: Any time you are rolling the Sincerity Skill to convince someone of what you are saying, you must call an extra Raise for no effect, or the roll automatically fails." Roll="61-70" />
              <Seperator />
              <Line Result="Control: Re-roll any Social Skill Roll, once per session," Roll="71-74" />
              <Line Result="Determination:  Negate all TN/Wound penalties on one Skill or Spell Casting roll, once per session." Roll="75-78" />
              <Line Result="Insight: Re-roll any roll that used the Awareness Trait, once per session." Roll="79-82" />
              <Line Result="Knowledge: Re-roll any roll that used the Intelligence Trait, once per session." Roll="83-86" />
              <Line Result="Perfection: any one die of your choice on a Skill Roll to explode , once per session." Roll="87-90" />
              <Line Result="Strength: Re-roll any damage Roll, once per session." Roll="91-94" />
              <Line Result="Will: negate 10 Wounds at the moment they are suffered, once per session." Roll="94-98" />
              <Line Result="Temporally gain (a rank of) the Perceived Honour advantage." Roll="99" />

            </RolledResultTable>
          </Effect>
        </SpecialAbility>  
      </SpecialAbilities>
    </Abilities>
  </Cruch>
</Entity>
```

Seems fairly nice. (Though I'm not adverse to changing it around.)
Only thin i'm a bit iffy about is the RolledResultTable.

Anyway, now that I've produced such a document I need to put it into more human consumable form.
I am aware there are mechanisms for this. something called a XSLT? I know CSS can be used for this (I tried it once, in a siple way), but I've heard the arn't the advised way of doing things.
The only way I know is to write a C# program that interprets the Xml. (which doesn't seem like a great solution)
So how to I go about making a nice human readble form out of an XML document?
If not with tables then at least with headings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is used to transform XML into another form. If you want to change that XML into HTML or other typographical forms, XSLT is an excellent way to do so and far easier than trying to reinvent the XSLT wheel with C#.

CSS is for styling what you have. Setting fonts, adding colors and borders to put it simply. It's not used to put things into human readable form. XSLT is for that.

Answer (score 3):

Include an XSL style sheet at the top of your XML document as such:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="rpg.xsl"?>
```

Then within this style sheet you can use some simple operations to transform your xml document into HTML which can then be styled with CSS. Here is some basic XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>

 <h2>Rings</h2>
   <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>Earth</th>
    <th>Fire</th>
    <th>Air</th>
    <th>Water</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="Entity/Rings">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="earth"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="fire"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="air"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="water"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>

</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps.

This is worth reading through: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: I haven't actaully tried it. But as I understand XSL (from your link)
The rings table will be empty, because valueof doesn't popup the value of attributes, right?